# Can, or should, I use a Dictionary instead of List(Of KeyValuePair) for storing POST form data?

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking a WebAPI method that captures all form POST data. The data coming in is in the format of `field_name field_value`. The names are all treated as strings, as are the values.

The controller captures all of the form data, converts it to JSON and stores it in the db. I now have a requirement to check if a specific field name exists in the list. I don't think this can easily be done with a `List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)` Is there a specific reason a dictionary would not work in this use case?

```
Dim _FormData As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
For Each item In FormData
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value)) AndAlso (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(item. Key)) Then
        _FormData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(item.Key, item.Value))
    End If
Next
            
Dim JsonCapture = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_FormData)
Dim FID = ""
If Not IsNothing((From p In FormData Where p.Key = "fid").FirstOrDefault()) Then
    FID = (From p In FormData Where p.Key = "fid").FirstOrDefault().Value
End If
```

Would there be any specific reason why `Dictionary(Of String, String)` would not work as a better replacement?

Comment: A `Dictionary<T, R>` requires all `T` to be unique, a `List<KeyValuePair<T, R>>` does not. If you can guarantee uniqueness, a `Dictionary` may be easier to handle in code. But it is somewhat trivial to determine the existence of a "key" in either case...

Comment: Not only does a Dictionary enforce uniqueness of keys, it also provides efficient retrieval of values via keys. If you don't need those two things then you don't need a Dictionary but why use a KeyValuePair if the key is not a key? You probably ought to just use a tuple or a dedicated type of your own.